# Does Application Insights work with Azure functions on Linux .NET Core v3.1?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Does Application Insights work with Azure functions on Linux .NET Core v3.1?

It looks like it does not work out of the box.
I have got no logs, no application map, and the Application Insights bar is grayed out. The `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` is set.
For me it is not an option to switch to Windows, functions are running inside ASE with Linux containers plan.

Is it anyhow possible to activate App Insights for Azure function running on Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Please follow the steps below(if the azure function is already created without configuring application insight):

1.In azure portal -> nav to you function app -> in the Functions menu, click your function. Screenshot is as below:

[image]

2.Then click the "setup" next to "Application insights" tag. Screenshot is as below:

[image]

3.Then click the "Configure" button. Screenshot is as below:

[image]

4.In the new page, you can choose to create a new Application Insights instance or link to an existing Application insights. Screenshot is as below:

[image]

At last, run the azure function, then nav to the application insights, you can see the logs are shown there.

And another way is that, when create a new azure function for linux in azure portal, you also have the chance to add application insights at that time.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. What a messy user interface btw here. It is mostly very intuitive in Azure but definitely not this time.